# How can I log into youtube on a chrome browser without logging into Chrome?

Tags: youtube, google-chrome

I have a google account and use chrome at home and at work.

At home I log into chrome and it automatically logs me in to youtube.com.

At work, I use chrome as a guest, but am able to log into StackExchange using my google auth. When I log into youtube.com using my google account, it logs into the chrome browser as me.

How can I keep the browser account as guest while logged into an account on youtube.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I had a conversation with support on youtube.com and as of the current date, this is not possible.</s>

This is possible by setting the Allow Chrome sign-in to false in chrome://settings/syncSetup

Found at https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/google_sites_without_chrome.html